# Show that $\tan x$ is bounded by the following expressions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, inequality

> $1.$ Prove that $\tan x> x+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{2x^5}{15}$ for $0< x< \dfrac{\pi}{2}.$
>
> $2.$ Prove that $\tan x < x+ \dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{2x^5}{5}$ for $0< x< 1.$

Here's what I've done:

$1.$

We know that $\sin x < x$ for $0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}.$ Thus, $x-\sin x>0$ for $0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}.$ Let $f'(x)=x-\sin x>0$ for $x\in(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}).$ Then $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{2}+\cos x.$ By the Mean Value Theorem, $\exists x_1 \in (0,x)$ such that $f'(x_1)=\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}= \dfrac{\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos x-1}{x} >0.$ So $\cos x> 1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}$ for $x\in (0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}).$ Let $g'(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\cos x-1>0$ on $(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}).$ Then $g(x) = \dfrac{x^3}{6}+\sin x-x$ and by the MVT, there exists $x_2\in (0,x)$ such that $g'(x_2)=\dfrac{\frac{x^3}{6}+\sin x-x}{x}>0\Rightarrow\sin x>x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}.$ Let $h'(x) = \dfrac{x^3}{6}+\sin x- x.$ Then $h(x) = \dfrac{x^4}{24}-\cos x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}.$ By the MVT, $\exists x_3\in (0,x)$ such that $h'(x_3)=\dfrac{\frac{x^4}{24}-\cos x-\frac{x^2}{2}+1}{x}>0\Rightarrow \cos x<1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^4}{24}$ on $(0,\frac\pi2).$ Let $i'(x) =  \dfrac{x^4}{24}-\cos x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+1 >0$ on $(0,x).$ Then $i(x)=\dfrac{x^5}{120}-\sin x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}+x$ and by the MVT, $\exists x_4\in(0,x)$ such that $i'(x_4)=\dfrac{\frac{x^5}{120}-\sin x-\frac{x^3}{6}+x}x{>0\Rightarrow\sin x<x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}+\dfrac{x^5}{120}}$ for $x\in (0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}).$ Now, repeating the process two more times gives that for $x\in (0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}), \sin x > x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}+\dfrac{x^5}{120}-\dfrac{x^7}{5040}.$ We also know that $\cos x < 1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^4}{24}.$  Thus, we have that for $0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2},$

$$\tan x = \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x} > \dfrac{\sin x}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}} > \dfrac{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}} \\
= x+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{2}{15}x^5+\dots > x+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{2}{15}x^5$$ as all terms that follow $\dfrac{2}{15}x^5$ are positive.

$2.$

We know from above that for $x\in (0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}),$
$\cos x > 1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}$ and $\sin x < x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}+\dfrac{x^5}{120}.$ Thus, $$\tan x < \dfrac{\sin x}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}<\dfrac{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}=x+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{7}{40}x^5+\dfrac{7}{80}x^7+\dfrac{7}{160}x^9+\dots \\
<x+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+x^5\dfrac{7}{40}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^n}\text{ for }0<x<1 \\
<x+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{2}{5}x^5 \text{ as } \dfrac{2}{5} > \dfrac{7}{40}.$$

> I finished this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both estimates can be achieved by repeatedly using $\tan'(x) = 1 + \tan^2(x)$, or
$$
 \tan(x) = \int_0^x (1+ \tan^2(t)) \, dt 
$$ 
for $0 \le x < \frac \pi 2$.

---

For the lower estimate $(1)$ we use that $\tan(x) > 0$ on $(0, \frac \pi 2)$. It follows that for these $x$
$$
 \tan(x) > \int_0^x 1 \, dt = x \\
\implies  \tan(x) > \int_0^x (1 + t^2) \, dt = x + \frac 13 x^3 \\
\implies \tan(x) > \int_0^x (1 + (t + \frac 13 t^3)^2) \, dt
= \int_0^x (1 + t^2 + \frac 23 t^4 + \frac 19 t^6) \, dt \\
 = x + \frac 13 x^3 + \frac{2}{15} x^5 + \frac{1}{7 \cdot 9} x^7
> x + \frac 13 x^3 + \frac{2}{15} x^5  \, .
$$

---

For the upper estimate $(2)$ we start with
$$
 \tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} < \frac{x}{1-\frac 12 x^2} < 2x
$$
for $0 < x < 1$. It follows that for these $x$
$$
 \tan(x) < \int_0^x (1 + 4t^2) \, dt = x + \frac 43 t^3 \\
 \implies  \tan(x) < \int_0^x (1 + (t + \frac 43 t^3)^2) \, dt 
  = \int_0^x (1 + t^2 + \frac 83 t^4 + \frac{16}{9} t^6) \, dt \\
  = x + \frac 13 x^3 + \frac{8}{15}x^5 + \frac{16}{63} x^7 
  < x + \frac 13 x^3 + x^5 
$$
because $\frac{8}{15} + \frac{16}{63} < 1$. Finally,
$$
 \tan(x) < \int_0^x (1 + (t + \frac 13 t^3 + t^5)^2) \, dt 
=  \int_0^x (1 + t^2 + \frac 23 t^4 + \frac 19 t^6 + \frac 23 t^8 + t^{10}) \, dt \\
= x + \frac 13 x^3 + \frac{2}{15}x^5 + \frac{1}{63}x^7 + \frac{2}{27}x^9  + \frac {1}{11}x^{11} 
< x + \frac 13 x^3 + \frac{2}{5}x^5 
$$
because
$$
\frac{2}{15} + \frac{1}{63} + \frac{2}{27} + \frac {1}{11} = \frac{3266}{10395} \approx 0.32 < \frac 25 \, .
$$

Comment: thank you. Your solution helped me solve my problem the way I wanted to, even though you used quite a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

By the Taylor's formula for $x_0=0$ for any $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ there is $0<\theta<1$ for which
$$\tan{x}=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{\tan^{(7)}\theta x}{7!}x^7>x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}.$$
Because $$\tan^{(7)}x=\frac{16(4\sin^6x+114\sin^4x+180\sin^2x+17)}{\cos^8x}>0$$ for any $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.